# Mogrify: Getting cropped part as a new file

Tags: mogrify

I used `mogrify` CLI in order to crop a `50x50` sized patch from an image, where the coordinate of the patch's upper-left corner is `(100,200)`:

```
mogrify -crop 50x50+100+200 my_image.png
```

The problem is that `my_image.png` is overridden with the crop.

How can I output the cropped results into another file instead, leaving the original image as is? (i.e. `my_cropped_image.png`)

Comment: If it isn't possible to ask mogrify to do this (and I have no experience or knowledge of mogrify), then why not just make a copy of the file first, and crop the copy?

Comment: If it is not possible to ask mogrify to do that, I'll use this workaround. But I first want to look for a more conventional solution. I think it should be a very basic feature...

Comment: Have you tried just adding another filename to the command? `mogrify -crop 50x50+100+200 my_image.png output.png` ?

Comment: Yes - it overrides `my_image.png` and prints an error for not finding `output.png` - i.e. it tries to use also `output.png` as an input file that should be cropped and overridden